# jquery validate bootstrap tooltip show error like Cannot read property 'VERSION' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting the below error while using the jquery validate bootstrap tooltip js

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'VERSION' of undefined

```
at $.validator.defaultShowErrors (jquery-validate.bootstrap-tooltip.js:19)
at $.validator.showErrors (validatefield.js:523)
at $.validator.form (validatefield.js:438)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (validatefield.js:99)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:4435)
at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:4121)
at Object.trigger (jquery-3.1.1.js:4350)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.js:4901)
at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:374)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:139)
```

can anyone help me to figure out the issue , is that the issue with jquery version ?

Comment: I guess you are loading thisvalidate bootstrap js before jquery. Can you paste the order of the script in which you are loading then.

Comment: @squiroid no, it is after jquery only

'jqueryvalidatebootstraptooltip': {
   export: '$',
   deps: ['jquery','validatefield','bootstrap']
  }

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in plunker or fidlle or jsbin ?